# Understanding and memorizing git rebase parameters

Tags: git

So far the most confusing portion of git is rebasing onto another branch. Specifically, it's the command line arguments that are confusing.

Each time I want to rebase a small piece of one branch onto the tip of another, I have to review the git rebase documentation and it takes me about 5-10 minutes to understand what each of the 3 main arguments should be.

`git rebase <upstream> <branch> --onto <newbase>`

What is a good rule of thumb to help me memorize what each of these 3 parameters should be set to, given any kind of rebase onto another branch?

Bear in mind I have gone over the git-rebase documentation again, and again, and again, and again (and again), but it's always difficult to understand (like a boring scientific white-paper or something). So at this point I feel I need to involve other people to help me grasp it.

My goal is that I should never have to review the documentation for these basic parameters. I haven't been able to memorize them so far, and I've done a ton of rebases already. So it's a bit unusual that I've been able to memorize every other command and its parameters so far, but not rebase with `--onto`.

Comment: You could either define some git aliases for your common use cases, or knock up a wizard script that reminds you what each of the parameters means before executing the command.

Comment: Ah, these mindblowing, pure elegance of git command options. So intuitively to use. Always a real pleasure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's skip `--onto` for the moment.  `upstream` and `branch` are pretty basic, and actually sort-of mimic `checkout` and `branch` - the second argument is optional:

```
git branch <newbranch>
git branch <newbranch> <base>
git checkout -b <newbranch>
git checkout -b <newbranch> <base>
git rebase <upstream>
git rebase <upstream> <branch>
```

<sub>(Aside, the names of these arguments in `rebase`, "upstream" and "branch" aren't very descriptive IMO.  I typically think of them like peachoftree, `<start>` and `<end>`, which is how I'll be using them:  `git rebase <start> <end>`)</sub>

When the second branch is omitted, the result is almost the same as first checking out that branch and then doing it as though you had not specified that branch.  The exception is `branch` which doesn't change your current branch:

```
git checkout <base> && git branch <newbranch> && git checkout <previous_branch>
git checkout <base> && git checkout -b <newbranch>
git checkout <end>  && git rebase <start>
```

---

As for understanding what `rebase` does when invoked, I first started by thinking of it as a special type of merge.  It's not really, but it helped when first starting to understand rebase.  To borrow peachoftree's example:

```
A--B--F--G master
    \
     C--D--E feature
```

A `git merge master` results in this:

```
A--B--F-----G master
    \        \
     C--D--E--H feature
```

While a `git rebase master` (while on branch `feature`!) results in this:

```
A--B--F--G master
          \
           C'--D'--E' feature
```

In both cases, `feature` now contains code from both `master` and `feature`.  If you're not on `feature`, the second argument can be used to switch to it as a shortcut:  `git rebase master feature` will do the same thing as above.

---

Now, for the special `--onto`.  The important part to remember with this is that it defaults to `<start>` if not specified.  So above, if I specified `--onto` specifically, this would result in the same:

```
git rebase --onto master master
git rebase --onto master master feature
```

<sub>(I don't use `--onto` without specifying `<end>` simply because it's easier to mentally parse, even thought those two are the same if already on `feature`.)</sub>

To see why `--onto` is useful, here's a different example.  Let's say I was on `feature` and noticed a bug, which I then started fixing - but had branched off of `feature` instead of `master` by mistake:

```
A--B--F--G master
    \
     C--D--E feature
            \
             H--I bugfix
```

What I want is to "move" these commits for `bugfix` so that they're no longer dependent on `feature`.  As it is, any sort of merge or rebase shown above in this answer will take the three `feature` commits along with the two `bugfix` commits.

For example, `git rebase master bugfix` is wrong.  The range `<start>` to `<end>` happens to include all the commits from `feature`, which are replayed on top of `master`:

```
A--B--F--G master
    \     \
     \     C'--D'--E'--H'--I' bugfix
      \
       C--D--E feature
```

What we actually want is the range of commits from `feature` to `bugfix` to be replayed on top of `master`.  That's what the `--onto` is for - specifying a different "replay" target than the "start" branch:

`git rebase --onto master feature bugfix`

```
A--B--F--G master
    \     \
     \     H'--I' bugfix
      \
       C--D--E feature
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a refresher, rebasing is mainly for when you want your commit history to appear linear if two branches have developed independently of one another, basically it rewrites commit history.

the way I like to do it is `git rebase --onto <target branch> <start branch> <end branch>`

where `<target branch>` is the branch you are rebasing onto, `<start branch>` is normally the branch from which `<end branch>` split and `<end branch>` is the branch you are rebasing.

if you start with

```
A--B--F--G master
    \
     C--D--E feature
```

and do

```
git rebase --onto master master feature
```

you will get

```
A--B--F--G master
          \
           C'--D'--E' feature
```

another good thing to know is that `<target branch>` defaults to `<start branch>` so you can do that same rebase as

```
git rebase --onto master feature
```

if you need more help, check out the [Rebase without tears](http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/rebase_without_tears.html) guide

Comment: Your result looks misleading. rebase should leave the `master` branch itself unchanged. You just get 'feature' to branch out like `G--C'--D'--E'` while `master` still stops at `G`.

Comment: @Frank, I did that to emphasize the whole linear history thing but now I think you're way is better. fixed.

Comment: Can you show an example where `<target branch>` and `<start branch>` are different so as to help readers understand the most general case?